# How to remember Picklist selection in Custom Edit Page

Tags: apex

I am having a Custom Object, which has a field `Country__c`. (Picklist).

When I am clicking the Edit page, it is going to a Custom Visualforce page. But, there in that page, `Country__c` is showing blank, as if it didn’t remember the country that was chosen.

I've written Extension Controller for this particular object.

Any solution for this?

Below is my Constructor for Extension Class

**Apex Code**

```
public class MyGroupConfigControllerExt {

    public final My_Config__c mpgcObj {get; private set;} 
    ApexPages.StandardController stdController;
    public list<SelectOption> specDiscountPicklist {get; private set;}
    public String selectedDiscount {get; set;}

    public MyGroupConfigControllerExt(ApexPages.StandardController Controller) {
        stdController = Controller;

        //we cannot use addFields within test methods, so we have to wrap it in a Test.isRunningTest()
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
            stdController.addFields(new List<String> {
                'country__c'
            });
        }

        this.mpgcObj = (My_Config__c)stdController.getRecord();
        // Here I have to set mbgObj.Country__c, but how???

        mpgcObj.Country__c = ?;



    }
```

Comment: Please post your code. The short answer is that you would need to set the Country on the field of the bound sObject in the constructor on page load.

Comment: @greenstork : Constructor code posted in the main question section

Comment: @greenstork : any example, how to use binding here

Comment: You should add the apex:inputField or whatever other way you are presenting the field in the Visualforce to the question too. By the way, your [addFields](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_addFields.htm) should result in the country being automatically queried for you by the standard controller.

Comment: @KeithC : 
1) I am presenting that field value in Selectoption
`<apex:selectList id="country" 
value="{!selectedDiscount}" size="1" multiselect="false">
<apex:selectOptions value="{!specDiscountPicklist}"/>
 </apex:selectList>`
2)I was getting an error, like query was retrieved without using necessary field.

So I had to use addFields.

I know How extension and Standards controller works. It should have worked.

Comment: It looks like you are binding the field to `selectedDiscount` which will never be read or written. (Setting `id="country"` is immaterial.) If you want the standard controller to take care of the reading and writing you will have to bind a field that is on the SObject e.g. `mpgcObj.Country__c` to your input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are displaying the string selectedDiscount on your Visualforce page, so that is what you need to set in your controller. If you are also using the visualforce page for new records and you want to have a default value for country you have to account for that as well. The following is what I have done to handle this previously:

```
public class MyGroupConfigControllerExt {

public final My_Config__c mpgcObj {get; private set;} 
ApexPages.StandardController stdController;
public list<SelectOption> specDiscountPicklist {get; private set;}
public String selectedDiscount {get; set;}

public MyGroupConfigControllerExt(ApexPages.StandardController Controller) {
    stdController = Controller;

    //we cannot use addFields within test methods, so we have to wrap it in a Test.isRunningTest()
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
        stdController.addFields(new List<String> {
            'country__c'
        });
    }

    this.mpgcObj = (My_Config__c)stdController.getRecord();

    if(mpgcObj.Country__c != null){
       selectedDiscount = mbgObj.Country__c;
    } else {
        selectedDiscount = 'Default Value';
    }
}
```

You will also want to make sure to override the save method, and make sure that you are saving the selectedDiscount into Country__c. See a previous answer I posted to my own question here for details: [Dynamically display fields based on Picklist for create page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22227/dynamically-display-fields-based-on-picklist-for-create-page)